# How to represent NoSQL entities

Tags: sql, uml, relational-database, nosql, mongodb

I've mainly studied SQL structures, and I know that the representation of the entities can look something like this:

[image]

However, I'm building this app with MongoDB, so NoSQL DB. I'm aware that MongoDB is non relational. Is there a standard way of representing these kind of databases?

Is it possible to use the previous format to represent my entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an UML class diagram is still relevant in a MongoDB context.

An entity is a class of domain objects, and regardless the database technology or the persistence format, ultimately you still manage objects:

- In a relational model, you need to segregate object by classes and squeeze this classes into one or several tables.
- In a document oriented DB model, the objects are persisted in an [object composition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) friendly format that easily allow to group objects that belong together via nesting.

You’ll find [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/437762/209774) some more arguments.
And on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67532753/3723423) you’ll find how this question relate to  Json schemas and mapping documents to class diagrams.